# Python - Call a django view from a button click - upload file from a form

Tags: python, django

I have this form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputFile">File input</label>
        <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="myfile">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

This form is in my index view:

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'App/index.html')
```

what i want to do is to let the user upload a file and some view has to do some work on it.

The thing is that i have another method to do the work on the file:

```
def do_some_work(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.FILES['myfile']

        lines = data.split("\n")

        ...
```

What i'm trying to do, without any success, is to link the "submit" button to this view

AND i don`t want to refresh the page. I know that being an http request the page must refresh

So questions:

In this case, is it necessary to have another url in my urls.py to handle this method? something like:

```
url(r'^work/$', views.do_some_work, name='do_some_work'), (I don't know if this is correct, i will figure it out)
```

How exactly can i call this function when clicking the submit button? Is there something missing in my form?

Is it possible to do not refresh the hole page? ajax?

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to structure it more like this:

```
# function to parse data
def do_some_work(data):
    # do something to data
    return processed_data

# view to receive request
def index(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        # parse posted data
        data = request.FILES['myfile']
        request_processed_data = do_some_work(data)
        context = {'data':request_processed_data}
        return render(request, 'App/index.html', context)

    else:
         # render form
         some_form = someForm()
         form_context = {'some_form':some_form}
         context = RequestContext(request, form_context)
         return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```